# Save the length and the value of a string into a byte

Tags: java

I need to save in the first byte position of the number of characters that has a string. Then store the value of each of the characters in the following positions.

```
 String cadena = new String ("Desarrollo"); 
byte valores[] = new byte [cadena.length()]; 
valores = cadena.getBytes();
```

Comment: What if the number of characters is bigger than the max value of a `byte`?

Comment: What is your question? Also, you probably should be using [String.getBytes(String charsetName)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `java.nio.ByteBuffer`. Get the `String` representation as a `byte[]` based on some given character set. Write the size of the `String` first as an `int`, then write the `byte[]`.

```
String cadena = new String("Desarollo");
byte[] bytes = cadena.getBytes("UTF-8");
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 + bytes.length); // 4 being the size of an int in bytes
buffer.putInt(cadena.length());
buffer.put(bytes);
```

You can then get the underlying `byte[]` with

```
buffer.array();
```

You should write the String length as an `int` because `byte` has a maximum value of 127, which you will probably surpass very fast.

Comment: This is the best way to do this.